# Trie Implementation in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, trie

I implemented a Trie in C++11, but I am not sure if my usage of `struct` and `std::unique_ptr`, and `std::unordered_map` are correct and *idiomatic*. Therefore, I hope someone could provide constructive criticism on my code.

My Trie implementation has three simple methods:

```
void Trie::Insert(const std::string&  word);
bool Trie::StartsWithPrefix(const std::string& prefix);
bool Trie::IsACompleteWord(const std::string& word);
```

#### Code

```
// tries.h
#ifndef TRIE_H_
#define TRIE_H_

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>


class Trie {
 public:
  // Trie Constructor
  Trie();
  explicit Trie(std::vector<std::string>);

  // Trie Operations
  void Insert(const std::string&  word);
  bool StartsWithPrefix(const std::string& prefix);
  bool IsACompleteWord(const std::string& word);

 private:
  struct Node {
    bool end_of_word;
    std::unordered_map<char, std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;
    Node(): end_of_word(false) {}
  };
  std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
};

/// ===========================
/// Tries Implementation
/// ===========================

Trie::Trie() {
  root = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node());
}

Trie::Trie(std::vector<std::string> words) {
  root = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node());
  for (auto w : words)
    Insert(w);
}

void Trie::Insert(const std::string&  word) {
  if (word.empty()) return;
  auto it = root.get();
  for (const char & key : word) {
    int found = it->children.count(key);
    if (!found)
      it->children.emplace(key, std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node()));
    it = it->children[key].get();
  }
  it->end_of_word = true;
}


bool Trie::StartsWithPrefix(const std::string& prefix) {
  auto it = root.get();
  for (const char & key : prefix) {
    auto found = it->children.count(key);
    if (!found)
      return false;
    it = it->children[key].get();
  }
  return true;
}


bool Trie::IsACompleteWord(const std::string& word) {
  auto it = root.get();
  for (const char & key : word) {
    auto found = it->children.count(key);
    if (!found)
      return false;
    it = it->children[key].get();
  }
  return (it->end_of_word) ? true : false;
}

#endif // TRIE_H_
```

#### Test

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch2/catch.hpp"
#include "trie.h"


SCENARIO("Trie operations", "[trie]") {
  GIVEN("A Trie Data Structure") {    

    Trie trie({"hello", "test"});

    REQUIRE(trie.StartsWithPrefix("hell") == true);
    REQUIRE(trie.StartsWithPrefix("helli") == false);
    REQUIRE(trie.StartsWithPrefix("test") == true);
    REQUIRE(trie.StartsWithPrefix("ab") == false);

    trie.Insert("ab");
    REQUIRE(trie.StartsWithPrefix("ab") == true);

    REQUIRE(trie.IsACompleteWord("ab") == true);
    REQUIRE(trie.IsACompleteWord("hell") == false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity. Any reason you are limited to C++11?

Comment: Dear bruglesco, thank you for your interest in my post. I decided to write C++11 (and not C++14 or C++17) because I am not sure if my code is even considered "modern" C++. During college, instructors only provide us C++98 so I would like to learn on my own modern C++. Eventually, I would love to write in the latest C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    bool end_of_word;
    Node(): end_of_word(false) {}
```

This would be probably more idiomatic simply written as

```
    bool end_of_word = false;
```

Next,

```
    explicit Trie(std::vector<std::string>);
```

is probably more idiomatic written as

```
    template<typename Itr> Trie(Itr begin, Itr end);
```

Next,

```
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
```

Why is it allocated on heap? It's a private member owned by this object, by putting it on heap you simply get some (noticeable) dereference overhead, and that's all.

Same goes for branches: there's no point in keeping child `Node`s on heap, `std::unordered_map<char, Node>` is quite sufficient for a tree, with no additional  overhead.

```
Trie::Trie() {
  root = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node());
}

Trie::Trie(std::vector<std::string> words) {
  root = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node());
```

Irrespective of what's said above about `root`'s type, such initializations are better put in initialization lists:

```
Trie::Trie(): root(new Node) {}
```

And if you upgrade to C++14, recall that [`make_unique` is the new `new`](https://abseil.io/tips/126)

```
Trie::Trie(std::vector<std::string> words)
  : root(std::make_unique<Node>())
{
```

Next,

```
  for (const char & key : word) {
```

`char` type is small enough to be bound by value. Scalar and small POD types, when passed by reference, can create unnecessary overhead so it is better written as

```
  for (char key : word) {
```

(or even

```
  for (auto key : word) {
```

which makes perfect sense if you ever decide to make character type a parameter to your Trie.)

```
    auto found = it->children.count(key);
    if (!found)
      return false;
    it = it->children[key].get();
```

In C++, even with unordered containers, it is better done as

```
    auto where = it->children.find(key);
    if (where == it->children.end()) return false;
    it = where->second.get();
```

And similarly for `Insert()`.

Which, by the way, I would declare as

```
  Trie &Insert(const std::string &);
```

But that is more like a personal preference.

How about adding a method that searches for all the elements whose keys start with a given prefix, and returns them either as a subnode, or a fresh container, like list or vector?

And the final boss: define an iterator type for your trie.

Comment: about `std::make_unique` the OP tagged the question `c++11`.

Comment: @Calak Thank you for fixing my typo. @bilpll. Thank you very much for providing feedback. I appreciate it. The reason I decided to allocate `root` on `heap` over `stack` because I thought it was a proper way to do so. Also, thank you for sharing the website abseil.io, it is truly great!